# get the filename from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument) and OnActivityResult() fine in my Android mobile app.  (Targeting Android 10, API 29).  The user selects an audio file and the app plays the file fine.  Ths user is able to select a file from anywhere on their device.

I would like to display the name of the file that is playing in the UI.  How do I grab the filename?

In OnActivityResult, this: ReturnedIntent.Data.Path,  returns this:

```
/document/content://com.microsoft.skydrive.content.metadata/Drive/RID/phil%40mydomain.com/Item/RID/DC9388F99D04BA56%21369828/Property/?RefreshOption=AutoRefresh&RefreshTimeOut=15000&CostAttributionKey=11-21-1
```

which has nothing resembling the file name in it.  I have found older stack posts on this, but they don't work for me.  I have a feeling that the issue is with Android security and/or permissions that I need to give the app.

How do I grab the file name so I can display it in the UI?

Comment: If this were Java/Kotlin, you would use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`, then call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile`. You will need to work out an equivalent solution in Xamarin. Note that this will give you a "display name", which may or may not be a filename, as the user may or may not be choosing a file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Hmmm, I don't think DocumentFile is returned to onActivityResult.  This is what is returned and I have drilled down "data" a lot.  
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
Ideas?

Comment: "I don't think DocumentFile is returned to onActivityResult" -- correct. A `Uri` is returned to `onActivityResult()`. You would then pass that to `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @CommonsWare, you pointed me in the right direction.  With the help of intellisense I noticed that the .Data property of the returned Intent was a Uri.  So this is what (C# Xamarin) ended up working.

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == -1 && requestCode == 42)
    {
        Intent ReturnedIntent = data;
    // the code is in a Fragment here so we use Activity for the Context
        DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(Activity, ReturnedIntent.Data);
        string FileName = df.Name;  // that contains the filename
```

I *never* would have got this on my own.  I love that Android Java and Xamarin C# are so close.  Thanks again @CommonsWare.